# How to get the first sentence from the first paragraph?

Tags: c#, regex, string, match

How to get the first sentence from the first paragraph?

```
 <h2>Test</h2>
 <p class="preserve">
      Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi. Euismod in pharetra a, diam.
 </p>
 <p class="preserve">
      Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi. Euismod in pharetra a, diam.
 </p>
```

My regex take all the sentences from the first and the second paragraph.

```
<p.*>.*\.\s[A-Z]
```

Comment: Use HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: Could you explain better what are your intent? Do you want to get this first paragraph from C# code...or it could be made via JS? Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by sentence or what you expect the extracted text to look like?  The normal English usage of sentence implies a group of words ending with a full stop.  From the comments on the answers you appear to be looking for something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

- setup single line mode
- skip first `p` tag and space charactes after it - `<p.*?>\s+`
- grab all before first dot `.*?\.`.

[regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/uK3zB8/1)

```
<p.*?>\s+(.*?)\.
```

Comment: But sentence is not just a DOT, but a CAPITAL LETTER after the space. Put a dot inside the first sentence so it stops to work.

Comment: @podeig Did you watch regex demo? I think you miss some details.

Comment: @podeig Dot is end of sentence. You can't put it inside sentence.

Comment: I think I got it right. Try to use "Morbi in sem quis dui . placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi. Euismod in pharetra a, diam." as a first sentence. It will take "Morbi in sem quis dui .", but I need the sentence. Dot can be a part of a sentence.

Comment: Yes I can. :) I work with data which have it. Sorry that I did not mentioned this in the task description.

Comment: @podeig Ok. You better know your application context. Note that you didn't say it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
/<p[^>]*>(.|\s)*([A-Z][^<.]*)\./gU
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/qT7rA3/4)

Comment: But sentence is not just a DOT, but a CAPITAL LETTER after the space. Put a dot inside the first sentence so it stops to work.

Answer (score 1):

This will put the first sentence of each paragraph in Group 1

```
<p.*>\s*([A-Z].+?)(?=\.\s[A-Z])
```